# Openldap ACLs don't work

Tags: openldap

I have following structure:

```
 dc=th,dc=company,dc=com
  |
  |->dmc
      |
      |->dmc_customer_company
```

I create a group to manage `write` access to `dmc_customer_company`.

Groups, divide by levels:

```
 app_all
 app_dmc
 app_dmc_company1
```

My script (formatted to help understanding)

```
  dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
  changetype: modify
  replace: olcAccess
  olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange 
      by self write 
      by anonymous auth 
      by dn="cn=admin,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" write by * none

  olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read

  olcAccess: {2}to * by self write 
      by dn="cn=admin,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" write by * read

  olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" 
      by self write 
      by group.exact="cn=app_all,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" manage 
      by * break

  olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree="o=dmc,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" 
      by self write 
      by group.exact="cn=app_dmc,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" manage 
      by * break

  olcAccess: {5}to dn.subtree="o=dmc_company1,o=dmc,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" 
      by self write 
      by group.exact="cn=app_dmc_company1,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" manage 
      by * break
```

I have user:

```
 cn=company1_admin,ou=application,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com
```

and:

```
 dn: cn=app_dmc_company1,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com
 objectClass: groupOfNames
 objectClass: top
 cn: app_dmc_company1
 member: cn=company1_admin,ou=application,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com
 member: ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com
```

I apply with: `ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f <file>`

I check configuration with: `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b "cn=config"` and they are inside configuration

Where am I wrong ? Because when:

- I use `company1_admin`
- to write or create some other users
- inside `o=dmc_company1,o=dmc,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com`

I receive `Ldap code: 50 LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS`

I use OpenLDAP without slapd.conf in Ubuntu 14.04. OpenLDAP is version 2.4.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would check the access to the 'children' pseudo entry

According to openldap-2.4 manual, acl section:

> To add or delete an entry, the subject must have write access to the entry's entry attribute AND must have write access to the entry's parent's children attribute

So, as a staring point:

```
olcAccess: {5}to dn.subtree="o=dmc_company1,o=dmc,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" 
  by self write 
  by group.exact="cn=app_dmc_company1,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" write 
  by * break

olcAccess: {6}to dn.children="o=dmc_company1,o=dmc,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" 
  by group.exact="cn=app_dmc_company1,ou=Groups,dc=th,dc=company,dc=com" write 
  by * break
```